# Is a good idea use template function in my site that retrieve HTML generated with PHP Smarty and display with ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty, response

My PHP framework

```
public static function insertAction(){

   .......

   \MVCApplication::getSmarty()->display('common/inserted.tpl');

}
```

Show to user using Ajax response: (JQuery)

```
success: function(response){
    $("body").html(response);
}
```

I want to make a site where all actions don't refresh the page (i.e., I want a dynamic site with just one page index.php).

My question is about security! I've read some articles on the web about the concern around script injection and my fear is that any malicious guy intercepts the response from the server and adds bad code to my server response! How do I improve my framework security?

(Eventually I will need execute script in my .tpl smarty templates and this will be outputted to ajax response too...)

Comment: +1 because you have your own php framework

Comment: There are a couple of mixed issues here. AJAX only works on the same domain, so it's unlikely injection will occur from server to client. However, it's possible that scripts added to your response data (e.g. from the database containing user-provided content, or uploaded files) may provide a vehicle for code injection. Likewise- parsing unverified url/action requests may cause issues if your controllers are not appropriately managed.  What methods do you allow for data to be sent back to your application? post, get, files, sessions?

Comment: I'm using POST to send back the data to client

Comment: `my fear is that any malicious guy intercepts the response from the server and adds bad code to my server response!` This is no more true with AJAX than it is with the bog standard page request. Less so, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whose security you're are talking about, the webserver or the client.
From what you have listed in the code, the server only sends data to the AJAX client, so it is not susceptible to a script injection attack since it is not acting on received scripts. (Although it is probably parsing a GET/POST response, but that is a different topic)

The fact that you use smarty doesn't make a difference with security, it is only a templating tool.

Javascript on the client is inherently insecure.  If you're that worried about script injections coming back to the client, don't use javascript.  As an alternative, you can try to strip any of the returned AJAX data to remove HTML or embedded scripts.

use something like: var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
from: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/